# 404 issue in adding a css file in laravel 5

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

I am new to `Laravel`. I want to add a CSS file in my `Laravel` project for my template. ın my project directory, I added a folder `assets`, and inside is `assets/css/style.css`

Now I am trying to apply it using `{{asset('assets/css/style.css')}}` but when I try to access `http://localhost:8000/assets/css/style.css`

I got an error of:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
> 1/1 NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8867:

Does anyone have an idea for this?

Comment: Is assets folder inside public folder? If it's not, then move it into public folder and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello please add your css like this.

```
{!! Html::style('assets/css/style.css') !!}
```

Comment: Please do note that Laravel 5 no longer has, by default, incorporated the Html facade. You'll have to manually add them into your project. They can be found [here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)